# Pdf not getting loaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using pdf package in flutter and trying to load an image using this:

```
final image = PdfImage.file(
    pdf.document,
    bytes: File('assets/logo.pdf').readAsBytesSync(),
  );
```

After that, I'm inserting it into the Image class:

```
 Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget> [
                Image(image)
              ]
            ),
```

But it gives this error:
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/logo.pdf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Why is it so, I'm not able to load the pdf?

Comment: Please do not start every one of your question titles with "Flutter:". This is what tags are for. Additionally, please explain your understanding of the error you see and what you found about it in your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets are not the same as files. You cannot access their data in the same manner. You're currently trying to access the `assets/logo.pdf` from the *device filesystem*, not from your apps assets, so it expectedly does not exist.

To get asset data you need to use the `rootBundle` with the `load` method.

```
final image = PdfImage.file(
  pdf.document,
  bytes: (await rootBundle.load('assets/logo.pdf')).buffer.asUint8List(),
);
```